# In what forms do plants and animals excrete sulfur?

Tags: biochemistry

Sulfur is part of the amino acids cystein and methionin, plants take up sulfur [in the form of $H_2S$](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15607/in-biosynthesis-of-cysteine-and-methionine-where-does-the-sulfur-come-from). These organisms will also need a way to get rid of excess sulfur, how? In what compounds?
Judging by the smell of some farts, I guess $H_2SO_4$ plays a role, but I can't imagine that one get'S rid of all the sulfur this way.

Comment: Plants do not take up H$_2$S, this is limited to a few microorganisms. Plants take up soluble forms of sulphur as sulphates, and the surely do not build up sulfuric acid (which would destroy the cells). Have you looked at this topic: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/can-animals-absorb-atmospheric-sulfur/

Comment: Maybe you want to comment on this answer: http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/15609/3037 'He states it's H2S

Comment: Apparently, a number of plants can take up H$_2$S. http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0062048&representation=PDF. (x-posted from other answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Sulfur is $3^{rd}$ most abundant mineral element in the body. Carnivores obtain it from Cysteine and Methionine in the animal protein which converted in to Glutathione.
Excess of sulfur is stored into Glutathione or oxidised to sulfate by sulfite oxidase which is eventually eliminated by urine.

[image]

[1]: [Nimni ME, Han B, Cordoba F (2007). "Are we getting enough sulfur in our diet?". Nutr Metab (Lond) 4 (1): 24. doi:10.1186/1743-7075-4-24](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2198910)

[2]: [Wikipedia on Sulfur metabolism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_metabolism)